# Redirecting user based on state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Right now, my router looks like this:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route component={Provider}>
        <Route path="/" component={AppPage}>
            <Route path="login" component={LoginPage}/>
            <Route component={LoggedinPage}>
                <Route path="onboarding" component={OnboardingPage}/>
                <Route component={OnboardedPage}>
                    <IndexRoute component={HomePage}/>
                    <Route path="settings" component={SettingsPage}/>
                </Route>
            </Route>
        </Route>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

`LoggedinPage` redirects to `/login` if the user isn't logged in and `OnboardedPage` redirects to `/onboarding` if the user hasn't completed the onboarding flow (choosing username, etc). However, I think more of these conditional redirects may be needed in the future. What's the best way to handle these conditional redirects? Is it possible to have a single component that handles all the redirects?

Comment: You shouldn't store jwt tokens inside of localStorage. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133536/is-it-safe-to-store-a-jwt-in-localstorage-with-reactjs

Answer (score 1):

`<Route>`s accept an `onEnter` hook that is called when the route matches. A hook would look something like this:

```
function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
    if (!loggedIn()) {
        replace({ pathname: 'login' });
    }
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
<Route path="/" component={AppPage}>
    <Route path="home" component={HomePage} onEnter={requireAuth}/>
    <Route path="login" component={LoginPage}/>
</Route>
```

---

A more composable example, that lets you combine multiple checks:

```
function checkAuth() {
    if (!loggedIn()) {
        return { pathname: 'login' };
    }
}

function checkOnboarding() {
    if (!completedOnboarding()) {
        return { pathname: 'onboarding' };
    }
}

function redirect(...checks) {
    return function(nextState, replace) {
        let result;
        checks.some(check => {
            result = check();
            return !!result;
        });
        result && replace(result);
    };
}
```

Then combine away!

```
<Route path="/" component={AppPage}>
    <Route path="home" component={HomePage}
        onEnter={redirect(checkAuth, checkOnboarding)}/>
    <Route path="login" component={LoginPage}/>
    <Route path="onboarding" component={OnboardingPage}
        onEnter={redirect(checkAuth)}/>
</Route>
```

Comment: +1, That's a good approach, only thing that bothers me is that replace refreshes the entire window and this is not contained within the SPA style.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a function that checks the if the user is logged in, and just import that:

```
import {browserLocation} from './browser-location'
export default function checkLoggedIn() {
    if (localStorage.jwt === null)
        browserLocation.pushState('/login')
}
```

Comment: I'll have to parse the URL manually this way right? Like I'll need `if (localStorage.jwt === null && !window.location.pathname.match(/^\/login(\/|$)/))`Is there a way to do this and still use React Router to parse the URL?

Comment: I redid my answer. So, you just import this function and call it in the render portion of your component to which you are routing.