# is it safe to use react js state to store token of authenticated user?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, authorization, react-lifecycle

I am implementing a simple user authentication system using react js and node js api. This is what i am doing inside **ComponentWillMount** method :-

1.checking if the token exits (in localStorage)
2.if it doesn't exits then the value of state 'token' will stay blank 
3.if it exists then checking if it's valid using an request to backend.
4.If the token is valid then state 'token' as localstorage.token 
5.If the token is invalid then the value of state 'token' will stay blank

inside render method i have added conditional rendering based on the value of state 'token' i.e. if the state 'token' is blank then normal page will be rendered else it will be redirected to user's page.

**The problem is** i can change the value of state 'token' using any react developer tool. And that is causing a loophole to login using a fake token.To avoid that i have to check for the validity of state 'token' everytime it is changed using one of the life cycle methods like **componentDidUpdate shouldComponentUpdate** . But as mentioned in the official documentation of react
  ***shouldComponentUpdate*** only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a rendering, as this can lead to bugs. 

Using **componentDidUpdate** isn't useful as it will be called after component will already be changed due to state change.

Using **componentWillUpdate** is mentioned as Unsafe in the official documentation

I am not sure how can i tackle this loophole.
Here is the code for the component

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Link,
    Switch,
    Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './Home';
import Nav from './Nav';
import Login from './Login';
import Signup from './Signup';

class Out extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();        

        this.state = {
            token : '',
            isLoading:false            
        }
        this.isLoading = this.isLoading.bind(this);
    }

    logout(){
        alert('logged out');
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        let {match} = this.props;
        this.navNoSessionRouteData = [
            {to:`${match.url}login`,name:'Login',key:'r1'},
            {to:`${match.url}signup`,name:'signup',key:'r2'},
            {to:`${match.url}`,name:'Home',key:'r3'}
        ];

        this.navNoSessionButtonData = [];

        this.setState({
            isLoading:true
        });

        const tokenVar = localStorage.getItem('token');
        if(tokenVar == null){
            console.log('not logged in');
            this.setState({
                isLoading:false
            });
        }else{            
            fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/account/verify?token='+tokenVar)
            .then(res=>res.json())
            .then(json=>{
                if(json.success){
                    console.log('logged in');
                    this.setState({
                        token : tokenVar,
                        isLoading:false
                    });
                }else{
                    this.setState({                 
                        isLoading:false,
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }

    isLoading(){
        let {isLoading,token} = this.state;
        if(isLoading === true){
            return (
                <p>Loading...</p>
            );
        }
        else{
            let {match} = this.props
            console.log(token);
            return(
                <div>
                    {
                        (token)?<p>Logged In</p>:(<p>NOT logged IN</p>)
                    }
                    <div className = "row">
                        <Nav navRouteData = {this.navNoSessionRouteData}  navButtonData = {this.navNoSessionButtonData}/>
                    </div>
                        <div className="row justify-content-center">
                            <Switch>
                                <Route exact = {true} path={`${match.path}`} component={Home} />
                                <Route path={`${match.path}login`} component={Login}/>
                                <Route path={`${match.path}signup`} component={Signup}/>
                            </Switch>
                        </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }


    render(){    
        return(
            <div>
                {this.isLoading()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Out;
```

[image: image is showing logged in user using real token][image: image is showing logged out user with blank token][image: image is showing logged in user with fake token]

Comment: Since a fake token wouldn’t work anyway is there actually a problem? A token needs to be stored somewhere and the user can change it however it’s stored.

Comment: I am not even sure this is a loophole. Worst case scenario the user will mess with his own token and will need to authenticate again.

Comment: it's a problem if i want to provide some services that i want to be accessible only to logged in users and those should stay hidden for the fake token

Comment: any user who is not logged in can add any value to state 'token' and will be able to see the hidden content .

Comment: Well if you are going to accept any token, since they are fake, you can't really stop them from doing this. If you store information in the client-side not matter how you do it a determined user will find a way to alter it.

Comment: I do agree wit you nikos. Can you suggest any other implementation to achieve the same?

Comment: I would probably not design it to use a verify api call `/api/account/verify?token='+tokenVar`. But I would require each sensitive api request to include a token from the user. If the token is invalid tell them so and give them a redirect to a login page where the token can be persisted locally.

Comment: But still you'll have to store the result of api request in a variable and that's the problem .The user can change it.You 'll have to attach some listener to check the changed value again and again

Comment: Is it possible some one could copy the token from the browser and reuse it within expiration time period

Answer (score 4):

Just to loop in here, I would answer this in two questions:

> (I think closer to your question): If I can edit React state variables, how is anything I display secure?

The point here is they CAN navigate to UI that requires them to be signed in, but when they actually go to request data (either to your backend, or directly to your database like Firebase) then they will need a valid token to do so. Your backend should be checking for this, and won't return any valuable data.

> If I can read React state variables, how safe is my token from being stolen and used by someone else to request and write data?

For this, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133536/is-it-safe-to-store-a-jwt-in-localstorage-with-reactjs)