# Store token on local storage is good or bad?

Tags: angular, security, oauth-2.0, local-storage, token

I created an application with **Java 8, spring boot, hibernate, jpa, spring security with OAuth2 and the services REST for back end**. **For the front end I use**d **Angular 7**. In my application I have users with roles. so when an user connected I generate an **OAuth2 bearer token** and I store that  in local storage, so when I need a resource I use that token to get it. when Logout I clear all data on local storage, so when a 2nd user connect I generate 2nd token etc...

***My question is whether this is a secure method or there is a better way to store and reuse token and the object user connected?***

***I talk about security vulnerabilities.***

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133536/is-it-safe-to-store-a-jwt-in-localstorage-with-reactjs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to store a jwt in localStorage with reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133536/is-it-safe-to-store-a-jwt-in-localstorage-with-reactjs)

Comment: I think cookies is better...