# How to persist login after refresh in react-redux app using JWT

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, local-storage

In my react/redux app, i have a problem where the app doesn't persist login after refresh. I'm using JWT token for my authentication. Below is my code for the auth actions file named *auth.js* and my auth reducers file named *auth.js* as well.

If there is a way i could make all my private routes check for the token and makes sure that i'm always logged in after refresh, kindly advice.

**My action**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { setAlert } from "./alert";
import {
  SIGNUP_SUCCESS,
  SIGNUP_FAIL,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_FAIL,
  LOGOUT,
} from "./types";

export const login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };

  const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

  try {
    const res = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:8000/api/token/",
      body,
      config
    );

    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data,
    });

    dispatch(setAlert("Authenticated successfully", "success"));
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_FAIL,
    });

    dispatch(setAlert("Error Authenticating", "error"));
  }
};
```

**My reducer**

```
import {
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
} from '../actions/types'

const initialState = {
    token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
    isAuthenticated: null,
    loading: false
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    const { type, payload } = action

    switch (type) {
      case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
        localStorage.setItem("token", payload.access);
        return {
          ...state,
          isAuthenticated: true,
          loading: false,
          token: payload.access,
        };
}
```

**My index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**Edit:** I have been adviced localStorage is not safe, if **cookies** is a safer alternative. Kindly assist with the solution implementation.

Answer (score 0):

While you're importing the token into Redux, `isAuthenticated` is still false, so I assume your application is checking for `isAuthenticated` being true and finding its not.

You would need to attempt to perform an action in the `componentDidMount` call of `<App />` to check to see if there is a usable token and if the server recognizes it as valid. This is because simply having a token doesn't confirm it's a **valid** token and that the user is authenticated.

For if that call returns successfully, create a new action type called `LOGIN_RETURNING` or such that sets `isAuthenticated` to true, then your routes will now recognize you as logged in.

For if that call returns with an error, I'd run a `LOGOUT` action that sets `isAuthenticated: false` and `token: undefined` (or `null`).

**Edit:** Additionally, I'd caution against using localStorage for your JWTs as localStorage can be attacked via XSS. See [Is it safe to store a jwt in localStorage with reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133536/is-it-safe-to-store-a-jwt-in-localstorage-with-reactjs) for more info.