# is storing JWT token in local storage safe?

Tags: angular, laravel, jwt

I m creating a web app, basically an Admin control panel, using Angular and Laravel and used JWT to secure my apis.
My question is - if jwt token stores in local storage which is being used to authenticate all my api request, what if someone copy jwt token from local storage, and use it for api requests separately from the app? Then how is it secure? and what is the way secure it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133536/is-it-safe-to-store-a-jwt-in-localstorage-with-reactjs

Comment: Generally speaking, holding a JWT is equivalent from an auth point of view as having possession of user credentials.

Comment: Incorporating things like IP address, device characteristics, etc., which can all be encrypted and stored on the same localStorage object as the JWT, makes the authentication more secure. You cannot, however, ever be sure that the device is securely with its owner. With that in mind, a short-lived token that expires after a few minutes or hours (depending on your security requirements), forcing your users to log back in, also helps to secure your app.

Comment: okay, I understand, Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it safe to store a JWT in localStorage with ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133536/is-it-safe-to-store-a-jwt-in-localstorage-with-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe to save tokens in local or session storage. Those storages are vulnerable on XSS attacks. A good practise is to keep them in memory (as a variable) or as a http only cookie..

Comment: That's not entirely true. This question has been asked many, many times. Please reference one of the many answers here on SO, like this one... https://stackoverflow.com/a/44209185/781799

Answer (score 0):

It is unwise to store the JWT in local/session storage, because of the security risk described above.  The alternative, the only one I know of, is to use an httpOnly cookie, to be set by the back end server.  But, if the front end and back end run on different servers, this will be a third party cookie, and the browser providers are ending support for third party cookies.  It seems that we are forced to use local storage for this case.

One could store it in memory, perhaps in a closure, but the value is gone when the user refreshes the page.

-- Update: There is a solution in progress, which is to set the partitioned flag.  The browsers will continue to support such third party cookies, but they only apply for the top level site where they were originally set.  See [cookies having independent partitioned state](https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd/chips).  Some platforms, e.g. Express, have trouble setting this flag, but the problem is being worked.

Comment: The original answer is incorrect and easily verifiable throughout SO. Please either provide supporting evidence or consider revising your answer.

Comment: Incorrect? please explain

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44209185/781799 (which I also referenced in my comment to the answer below)

Comment: Your link does not contradict any of my answer, either the original or as updated.

Comment: The post contradicts your opening sentence "It is unwise to store the JWT in local/session storage". Storing JWTs in local storage is not perfectly secure, but it is not generally characterized as "unwise". There are many other similar questions all over SO that give the same widely accepted answer, which is that it's not perfect, but good enough for most use cases.