# Sending props from Document to NextApp component in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, content-security-policy

To implement [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP), I need to pass a random token generated in the `Document` component at `_document.js` file to the `NextApp` component at the `_app.js` file.

I want to do that **without using the request object or context**. I think it should be possible because the Document component [wraps](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/8fdcc52854007f64f079ce3b4a45f43269b8baec/packages/next/pages/_document.tsx#L54) the NextApp component.

Is there a clean way to send props from the Document component to the NextApp component in a clean and Next.js idiomatic way?

Comment: Perhaps web storage/client side cookie? I’m not sure about the security implementations of this but [heres an extensive post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44209185/10653440) that discusses the aforementioned. You could build a custom hook.

Comment: @msalla using web-based storage will fail if the app is rendered on the server which is where the token is coming from

Comment: Why don't you want to use context? That seems like the easiest way to go about doing this.

Comment: You should ask yourself if generating a token within the document file is a good idea to begin with. Why can’t you have your token generator in _app.js?

Comment: doesn't getServerSideProps help here?