# SvelteKit API requests with Axios JWT authentication

Tags: authentication, cookies, axios, svelte, sveltekit

I am creating an app with a SvelteKit client and a Laravel API stack, but I am struggling to safely authenticate my client to my API. Ideally I want to store a JWT token in my cookies that I send with requests to the Laravel API with Axios.

So far I have the token stored in my cookies, but the part that I can't get working is getting the JWT token from my cookies so I can send it in my `Authorization` header. I tried getting the token from the cookies in the `handle` hook, which works, and then adding it to my Axios headers. But this only seems to work server-side and not client-side.

> The API module I use to send requests

```js
import axios from 'axios'

class Api {
  private headers: Record<string, string> = {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
  }

  get axiosInstance() {
    return axios.create({
      baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api/',
      headers: this.headers
    })
  }

  get get() {
    return this.axiosInstance.get
  }

  get post() {
    return this.axiosInstance.post
  }

  get patch() {
    return this.axiosInstance.patch
  }

  setAuthorization(token: string): void {
    this.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
  }
}

const api = new Api()

export default api
```

> The `handle` hook

```js
export const handle: Handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
  const cookies = cookie.parse(event.request.headers.get('cookie') || '')

  const response = await resolve(event)

  if (cookies.jwt) {
    api.setAuthorization(cookies.jwt)
  }

  return response
}
```

If I console log the Axios instance it does show the `Authorization` header, but it is not being send with the request.

I did get it working by storing the JWT token in local storage, but this is not ideal security wise.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the axios option `withCredentials` is set to `true` (you should probably add it as a default request option when creating the instance to avoid repetition, but you can pass it with individual requests as well if you prefer).

See [Make Axios send cookies in its requests automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002444/make-axios-send-cookies-in-its-requests-automatically) for in-depth details.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I am still facing the same problem after enabling `withCredentials`. The `Authorization` header is not set client-side

Comment: localStorage or even better, sessionStorage would do. maybe encrypt/decrypt it with AES on the fly could work to obfuscate the actual data but still can be hacked (just have to decompile and find the key)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue, the cookie had the `HttpOnly` so the client had no access to the cookies. I solved this by simply removing the `HttpOnly` flag in my `Set-Cookie` header, which is not very safe, so any other methods of solving this issue are very welcome.

Comment: If localStorage and client-accessable cookies are generally safe enough for storing JWT tokens. If it's not safe enough, that means you're running untrusted javascript on your domain. In that case use HttpOnly cookies and perform the JWT operations in (svelte) endpoints. That way you can restrict the attacker to only those operations.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133536/is-it-safe-to-store-a-jwt-in-localstorage-with-reactjs