# localStorage is not available: ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined in Utils folder in nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, terminal, local-storage, storage

I am Trying to encrpty my localstorage data, it encrypted but it throws error.

MY code (./src/utils/secureLocalStorage.js)

```
import SecureStorage from 'secure-web-storage'
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'

const SECRET_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY

let secureLocalStorage = null

try {
   secureLocalStorage = new SecureStorage(localStorage, {
   hash: function hash(key) {
   key = CryptoJS.SHA256(key, SECRET_KEY).toString()
   return key
},
encrypt: function encrypt(data) {
  data = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, SECRET_KEY).toString()
  return data
},
decrypt: function decrypt(data) {
  try {
    data = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, SECRET_KEY).toString(
      CryptoJS.enc.Utf8
    )
    return data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error decrypting data:', error)
    return null
  }
},
})
} catch (error) {
  console.error('localStorage is not available:', error)
 }

export default secureLocalStorage
```

My error:
it comes in my terminal

[image]

Comment: looks like the code is running on the server, not the client. localStorage is only available on the client

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems here. Let's first talk about why you are seeing this error.
As you might already know, NextJS is a meta-framework mostly used for SSR(Server Side Rendering). The SSR means that the code has to run on the server in order to create a response. If it is running on the server then you won't have access to `window` since there is one. Only browsers have `window` object. This means there are no objects like `localStorage`.

Another problem is you are trying to create secure storage using `localStorage`. And since you are trying to use `localStorage`, this would mean it has to be client-side. If it is client-side, you would have to send the `SECRET_KEY` to the client. And this defeats the purpose of using secure storage.

If you could tell us about your application or use case for this, I or someone here might be able to suggest some alternatives.

[This](https://www.rdegges.com/2018/please-stop-using-local-storage/) might be useful to you.

Comment: i wish to hide or encrypt the data stored in localstorage

Comment: `localStorage` isn't suited for that. There is one answer that I found but I haven't used it. So, just look into it first. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73916413/7866138

Comment: I would strongly advice against storing sensitive data on `localStorage`. You are better off using `session-storage` with `httpOnly` and `secure` flags true.